# Unable to enable unlock 512MB RAM of Model B

Tags: memory

I want to set RAM to 384MB. I've tried several things to try and get the RAM above the 184MB shown below by running `free -h`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          184M        73M       111M         0B        10M        38M
-/+ buffers/cache:        23M       160M
Swap:          99M         0B        99M
```

I followed the instructions [here](http://hubcitylabs.org/unlocking-your-new-raspberry-pis-512mb-of-memory/), there was no change. I also added the following line to /boot/config.txt:

```
gpu_mem_512=128
```

Again, no change. I also tried following [this guide](http://www.raspians.com/updating-the-memory-split-for-the-512-mb-raspberry-pi/), but it returned error 404. (I can't see the file `arm384_start.elf` in my /boot directory).

What do I need to do to get it to work? I'm actually wondering if I loaded the correct image onto the SD card to start with - is it possible that I loaded the Model A's image? How can I tell?

Thanks

Edit: As per the link posted by @avra, the contents of /proc/cpuinfo is as follows:

```
Processor       : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS        : 697.95
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware        : BCM2708
Revision        : 0003
Serial          : 00000000da25038e
```

So since Revision < 5 it would seem it's the 256MB version?? It's odd since it has 2 USB ports and an ethernet port! Seems to conflict with [the RPi FAQ](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs):

> **What’s the difference between Model A and Model B?**
>   Model A has 256MB RAM, one USB port and no Ethernet (network connection). Model B  has 512MB RAM, 2 USB port and an Ethernet port.

Comment: Putting `gpu_mem=128` in the `config.txt` file should do it...

Comment: Thanks - I already have it set to 64, but I read that the gpu_mem_512 setting overrides it anyway?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a 512MB model? You can check it here: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=20255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model B Pi's had 256M of RAM initially, and this changed on [15th October 2012](http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/2180).

Your Pi was manufactured before this date and has 256M of RAM as indicated by the board revision.